# Lenovo Legion 5 Laptop video drivers How do I know if both GPUs are functioning?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lenovo, steam

I have the best laptop I have ever bought, a Lenovo Legion 5.  Problem is that it has two Graphics processors. One is a Ryzen 5000 series on the CPU processsor and the other is a Nvidia Geforce RTX.

How do I know if both are working on ubuntu? I don't even know if both of them are working in Microsoft Windows. I want to run the DOOM video game on Ubuntu. I paid for it with a steam acount and I'm about to dive in and see if it works on Ubuntu. Is this called hybrid graphics?

Thanks for any info. I suppose you need ab output in terminal of the x-server, but I have not messed with Ubuntu since the year 2010.

Have an awesome day..

McCall

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: You didn't provide any Ubuntu product/release details (*though use of a Desktop system can possibly be assumed*), but release may matter. Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choices; the significance of this is that what are commonly called *drivers* are actually kernel modules; thus the kernel stack choice changes kernel modules (ie. different *drivers*)... Also Xorg (xserver) is mandated now; though I suspect you'll still want to use it.